# how to install Ubuntu from 1TB external HDD (clasic 5400rpm) - NOT USB

Tags: hard-drive

I don't have a USB stick, so I am using external HDD. It is an old 5400 rpm hdd.
And I don't have CD reader.
Therefore I am using old WesrernDigital MyBook HDD. It is an external HDD pluged in via USB port. I formated the disk, and then I unzipped the ISO of UBUNTU onto the HDD.
My question is. 
How can I boot and install that ubuntu from an external hdd?

When I was installing windows 10 I used this manual>

*

> Using Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8 open CMD as
>   Administrator (Windows key + R, type CMD, hit Enter) Enter the
>   following commands, (replace X with what applies to your hard drive):
>   diskpart; 
>   list disk; 
>   select disk X; 
>   list partition; 
>   select partition X;
>   active; 
>   exit; 
>   X:\boot\bootsect.exe /nt60 X:

*

but now I cant use BOOTSECT.EXE because there is GRUB

Please, how to continue or how to create from hdd the external bootable hdd?

Answer (score 0):

Unzipping ISO onto a HDD is not sufficient, you need to make your HDD bootable. You need a dedicated software to do that. On your Windows machine download UnetBootin https://unetbootin.github.io/ or Rufus https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows and make your HDD bootable. The usage should not be difficult, just follow the instructions on the software website. Personally, I have used only Unetbootin, haven't tried Rufus. After you've made your HDD bootable just leave it plugged in and reboot the system. Your computer should detect it automatically at start up and launch the installation for you from your HDD, if not, then set your HDD as bootable in BIOS.

Comment: So I tried both: Rufus and Unetbootin .. nothing works. Both can't see the WD external HDD as an option where to unpack the iso file.
I tried to format the external hdd into FAT32 system. But it didn't work. Cuz it is 1TB hdd. So I created 5GB size on that 1TB which is FAT32 formated. And the rest is unformated. Still nothing. My computer see this HDD but it can't be set as bootable. I don't know why. 
There must be a sollution.
When I was installing the Win10 from this HDD I was able to set it via the Bootsec.exe file. Now I can't.

Comment: Linux needs ext4 partition, Fat32 is not for Linux file system. Born Rufus and Unetbootin should have an option to format the partition for Linux file system